# Is there a list of punctuation commands for iPad dictation?

Tags: ipad, voice-dictation

I'm sure Apple has published something similar for Siri, but now that the iPad dictation is out, where can I find a list of commands for dictation? Can I do things like hit the enter key, or type symbols? I'm obviously able to enter periods and question mark's, but beyond that I'm not so sure. So, how can I type out the words question mark Without actually getting a question mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siri dictation is never going to be 100% accurate and the easiest way to get the result you want may be to edit the text *by hand* after you've dictated the body of the message.

Jim Rhoades provides a useful list of [Siri dictation commands](http://blog.crushapps.com/2011/10/more-fun-with-siri-dictation/).